# How to get a greater than record in Hibernate - Criteria Queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Amount value is type of Big Decimal and logic should be **_customerPayeeTransaction.getAmount() > 10 000.00**

How to change following Criteria to match with above logic?

```
Criterion amount = Restrictions.gt("cpt.amount", _customerPayeeTransaction.getAmount());
```

Please Help me.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is the issue that your amount is `BigDecimal`?

Comment: i want to implement that logic above mentioned .

Comment: _customerPayeeTransaction.getAmount() > 10 000.00

Comment: well, to me it looks like you are done

Comment: if i write this Criterion amount = Restrictions.gt("cpt.amount", _customerPayeeTransaction.getAmount()); will it filter amount values grater than 10 000.00 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If u want to add filter amount lower than 10 000 : 

Criterion amount = Restrictions.lt("cpt.amount", new BigDecimal("10000.00"));
```

Comment: .lt or .gt it depend what u want :)